# Referencing the subequations block doesn't show the section number

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, labels, subequations

I am new to this stackexchange group so forgive me if my question is not proper. If some extra information is required then kindly comment, I will attach those details.

I am using the following lines

```
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
& y = (c-r_x)*x + r_x*gbest, \label{eq:0.1} \\
& y = (c-r_n)*x - r_n*gbest, \label{eq:0.2} \\
\end{align}
\label{eq:eqn}
\end{subequations}
```

But calling `\cref{eq:eqn}` prints eq.(1) instead of eq(.1). This doesn't happen when I am referencing the subequations. Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `\cerf`. Is it maybe a typo and should say `\cref`, which is a macro provided by the `cleveref` package? Please also tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MSE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` in the preamble instead of putting `\thesection` inside `\theequation`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{TEST}

Intro

\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
& y = (c-r_x)*x + r_x*gbest, \label{eq:0.1} \\
& y = (c-r_n)*x - r_n*gbest, \label{eq:0.2} 
\end{align}
\label{eq:eqn}
\end{subequations}

And then refer to equation \ref{eq:0.2}, which is within \cref{eq:eqn}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3} % just for this example
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
y_x &= (c-r_x)x + r_x g_{\mathrm{best}}, \label{eq:0.1} \\
y_n &= (c-r_n)x - r_n g_{\mathrm{best}}  \label{eq:0.2} 
\end{align}
\label{eq:eqn}
\end{subequations}
\verb|\cref{eq:eqn} and \cref{eq:0.1}| produces
``\cref{eq:eqn} and \cref{eq:0.1}''.
\end{document}
```